# disable verification mail for api in auth0

Tags: email, auth0, rules, email-verification

I currently have two api in auth0, one needs that when someone registers confirm or verify your mail, but the second api, you do not need this option to verify email.
I see that in the mail section-> templatesand verification mail is active, but if I disable  it, the mail will never arrive to verified the user of the first api, but if I leave it active, an email will arrive to verify mail to the user of the api2. My idea is to create a rule for this case but I do not know how and I do not find documentation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment the email verification option in the dashboard applies globally to all your Applications when enabled.

An alternative is to turn off the verification email template for your tenant, and use the `/api/v2/tickets/email-verification` [endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Tickets/post_email_verification) from the Auth0 Management API to obtain an email verification ticket (an URL) that you can email to your users on registration or any other arbitrary event you want.

The downside of this approach is that you have to handle the email delivery on your side.